# Spoof user agent with GET /test.php HTTP/1.1 from socket?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, sockets, air, user-agent

I'm working on a tool that reads and executes html/javascript documents from a web server.
I use the RFC2817Socket (because i'm connection through a proxy) and send requests using  writeUTFBytes and displaying the page in a HTMLLoader (loadString); So far so good.
My question now, is there a way to spoof the user agent ? So even if i connect to the webserver via a proxy and send my request, i would like to be able to change the user agent to whatever i want.

```
_proxy.writeUTFBytes('GET /test.php HTTP/1.1\r\n');
_proxy.writeUTFBytes('Host: xx.xx.xx.xx:xx\r\n');
_proxy.writeUTFBytes('Connection: Keep-alive\r\n\r\n');
_proxy.flush();
```

the page i call is a php script that returns a bunch of information such as ip, referer, user agent... But user agent is never defined :

```
echo 'user agent:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
echo 'ip:'.getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
```

But it returns the correct ip address (the proxy's)

```
ip:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
user agent:
```

Comment: why not just use the URLRequestHeader in conjunction with a URLLoader http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: I'm going the socket way because in this app, i have a proxy manager that tests and returns working proxies and switches between proxies. I don't think i can do that using URLRequestHeader. Also everything works but that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a "User-Agent:" field to your request header:

```
_proxy.writeUTFBytes('GET /test.php HTTP/1.1\r\n');
_proxy.writeUTFBytes('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n');
_proxy.writeUTFBytes('Host: xx.xx.xx.xx:xx\r\n');
_proxy.writeUTFBytes('Connection: Keep-alive\r\n\r\n');
```